# NSTimeInterval and seeing if a date is more than an hour in the past

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I find dates very non-intuitive and confusing so here goes.

I have an array of events with dates and if the date of any single one is more than an hour in the past, I want to delete it.

Code I am using is:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
Events *event = mutableEventsArray[i];
if (event.date!=nil) {
    NSTimeInterval sinceNow = [event.date timeIntervalSinceNow];
    NSLog(@"sinceNow%@",sinceNow);
    NSTimeInterval hourInterval = 3600;
    if (sinceNow<hourInterval) {
        [mutableEventsArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
    }
}
```

The problem is that it is removing events that are less than an hour in the past.

In one example I just ran, logging `now` to console shows:

```
Mon May  7 11:52:31 2018
```

Logging event.date shows: `Mon May  7 11:35:42 2018`

The difference is 17 minutes or about 1020 seconds, way less than an hour.

However, when I log the time interval sinceNow to console  I am getting a negative number: sinceNow-97005.383634.  This number is bigger than 3600 let alone 1020.  So something seems wrong with the calculation `NSTimeInterval sinceNow = [event.date timeIntervalSinceNow];`

I [have read](http://woolybeastsoftware.com/woolyblog/tag/nstimeinterval/) that using `NSTimeInterval` does not take into account DaylightSavings Time and leap years, but don't see how that would be applicable here.

Would appreciate any suggestions on what issue might be.

Comment: Note that `sinceNow` is `-97005.383634`. That's a negative number. That means that the date is earlier than "now". And it is about 26 hours earlier than "now".

Comment: *"I find dates very non-intuitive and confusing"* - You may find [an article](http://www.maddysoft.com/articles/dates.html) I wrote useful.

Comment: Any time you think you should be doing date math by hand, you should probably visit this site and then reconsider your coding choices. ;)

http://yourcalendricalfallacyis.com.  (though you're probably cool here w/the > 3600 check -- just, be careful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be happier if you turn the calculation around:

```
NSTimeInterval ageOfEvent = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:event.date];
```

This gives `ageOfEvent` the meaning you expect: it is the elapsed time since the event, in seconds. So you can then say

```
if (ageOfEvent > 3600) {
    [mutableEventsArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`-[NSDate timeIntervalSinceNow]` returns a negative value for a date in the past and a positive value for a date in the future.
To check if a date is more than an hour ago, you should check if timeIntervalSinceNow is < -3600